# Using Internet Explorer 8 and 9 beta under internet options -advanced java does not show to check the box

Tags: java, internet, windows-explorer

I am using internet 8 and under internet options   advanced   there is not box to check to enable java.  I was told to reset which did nto work.  I have tried to uninstall java  6-21 32 bit but I get windows installer error 1723.  I brought up the java console and made sure it was pointing to the right target.  But I guess the main thing is I have no enable java under internet options, advanced. It was under security to enable java scripting.  Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

[1723](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28VS.85%29.aspx) error means:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Try redownloading the Java package and install it again. If it doesn't work install [Windows Installer 3.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=889482FC-5F56-4A38-B838-DE776FD4138C&displaylang=en) and ensure you have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

> But I guess the main thing is I have no enable java under internet options, advanced. It was under security to enable java scripting. Any answers?

I'm going to assume that your reference to "java scripting" is referring to the ability to turn JavaScript on and off in Internet Explorer. This has nothing to do with your attempts to install Java.

[JavaScript is not Java](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=javascript+is+not+java&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Going with what Sathya said, redownload the package and check Windows Installer. Rather than installing 3.1 (which is probably already installed), you might as well get the latest and greatest - [Windows Installer 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4&displaylang=en). Install that and try again.